# dimension of set of polynomials of degree at most 4 that vanish at 6.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set $S:=\{p(x) \in P_4(\mathbf{R})| p''(6)=0\}$. Find a basis for that set. And complete to a basis for $P_4(\mathbf{R})$. Then find $W$ sucht that $P_4(\mathbf{R})$
Here is what I tried:
second derivatives of polynomial of degree at most 4 is polynomial of degree at most 2. So taking twice antiderivatives $x^2-6^2, x-6$ would form a basis for $S$?

Now, suppose what I did above is correct, then, $x,1,x^2$ spans the orthogonal complement?

Comment: $x^2-6^2\not\in S$

Comment: The derivative of any constant polynomial is $0$ everywhere, so $1\in S$.

Comment: the second derivative of any linear polynomial is also $0$ everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question statement is unclear in places, but NB (as J.W. Tanner points out in the comments) that $x^2 - 6^2$ is not in $S$, as its second derivative is the constant function $x \mapsto 2$.

**Hint** Write out a generic element $p \in P_4({\bf R})$, then impose the condition $p''(6) = 0$.

> **Additional hint** One could write such an element as $$p(x) = b_4 x^4 + b_3 x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0$$ for constants $b_0, \ldots, b_4$ but the linear map $p \mapsto p''(6)$ evaluates $p''$ at $x = 6$, and we can speed up this computation by instead writing a generic element as a linear combination of powers of $x - 6$: $$p(x) = a_4 (x - 6)^4 + a_3 (x - 6)^3 + a_2 (x - 6)^2 +a_1 (x - 6) + a_0.$$ Now write $S$ in terms of conditions on the $a_i$.)